# Jquery remove select options based on text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms

I'm trying to do the following:

I have an input `<input type="text" value="red,yellow,blue" id="colors" />`

and a dropdown list

```
<select name="colors_dropdown" id="colors_dropdown">
   <option value="red">red</option>
   <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
   <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>
```

I want to remove the select options that are in the text input. For example if text input `value=red,blue` the dropdown should have just option `yellow`.

I was able to make arrays of the comma separated values in the text input and values in dropdown options.

```
var selected_colors = $('#colors').val().split(","); //array of colors from text input

var all_colors = $.map($("#colors_dropdown")[0].options, function(option)
                 {
                    return option.value; //array of all colors from dropdown
                 });
```

Based on that, I'm looking for a way to populate the dropdown list with all colors except those in the `selected_colors` arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var selected_colors = $('#colors').val().split(","); //array of colors from text input
jQuery.each(selected_colors, function() {
    $("#colors_dropdown option:[value='" + this + "']").remove();
    //Or use text attribute:
    //$("#colors_dropdown option:[text='" + this + "']").remove();
});
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/83Vg9/2/

Comment: I applaud your code sir. It's very compact and effective. I don't think it can be compressed more.

Answer (score 1):

This will remove the exact matching colors. Using `contains` could be remove all matching options for e.g. if the text box contains only `e` it will remove yellow, blue, red, green everything...

```
// make an array
var selected_colors = $('#colors').val().split(","); 

// iterate each color
$.each(selected_colors, function(index, color) {
    // iterate over each option & remove if necessary
    $('#colors_dropdown option').each(function(){
        if (this.value == color) {
            $("#colors_dropdown option:[value='" + color + "']").remove();
        }
     })
});
```

**EDIT**

Just realized that you don't need to use two `each()` as shown above. Try this -

```
// make an array
var selected_colors = $('#colors').val().split(","); 

// iterate over each color and remove it from the dropdown
$.each(selected_colors, function(index, color) {
    $("#colors_dropdown option:[value='" + color + "']").remove();
});
```